# Проблема линковки - ld multiple definition of

Tags: c, gcc

Не понимаю как решить данную проблему, у меня есть структура в файле `main.h` и нужно чтобы переменная данной структуры использовалась в нескольких модулях, для обращения к `value`. Но этого сделать не получается

Пример программы:
**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
void count();

int main(void)
{
  name.value = 2;
  printf("%d\n", name.value);
  count();
  return 0;
}
```

**count.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

void count()
{
  name.value = 5;
  printf("%d\n", name.value);
}
```

**main.h**

```
struct Main {
  int value;
} name;
```

Сборка:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c count.o
gcc main.o count.o -o program
```

Понятно что `name` определен повторно, ноо мне надо использовать содержимое структуры **Main** в разных модулях. Как исправить данное поведение?

Comment: Разделите определение структуры (можете сделать ей typedef, чтобы это было полноценным типом) и определение переменной. Определение глобальной переменной положите в какой-нибудь файл реализации (да хоть в main.c). В заголовочном файле (можно там же, где описана сама структура как тип) объявите эту переменную как extern. Проблема именно из-за того, что Вы определяете переменную в заголовочном файле, который потом включаете в разные файлы.

Comment: @Vladimir, помогло extern определение спасибо